# Django: view content in with a certain id

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlCcU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzL62.png)how can I make sure that with a certain category I only get the films of that category? (I attach photos of the models and views) thanks in advance
Sorry for the Englishenter image description here

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `Film` queryset by its `categoria` field, so:

```
Film.objects.filter(categoria__categoria='name_of_some_categoria')
```

If you have a primary key of the `Categorie`, which is the case in your `film` view if I understand that correctly, you can filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def film(request, pk):
    categorie = get_object_or_404(Categorie, pk=pk)
    films = Film.objects.filter(categoria_id=pk)
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'categorie': categorie, 'films': films})
```

where `films` contains the `Film`s belonging to the `Categorie` with `pk` as primary key.